# Why am I unable to validate iOS App Archive?

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader, xcode-organizer

I am getting the following error on attempting to validate my app through Xcode's organizer:

[image: General Error]

I have followed all the instructions I can find trying to fix this issue but to no avail. There are dozens of other threads out there that have many suggestions.

We recently renewed for another year and have rolled over into the second. I have literally revoked and regenerated all of our certs using new keys and have updated and regenerated provisioning profiles. I have never had this much trouble getting an update for one of our apps submitted. I'm at my wits end.

I understand that this 'technically' isn't a 'programming' question at its core, but I think the spirit of this should allow the question to stand in the hopes of other developers around here having run into this. (And yes, I will also be reporting a bug to Apple.)

So, how about it... anyone out there have the magic.

Comment: Could be part of iTunes Connect is down. Other users have been having difficulties the past 24 hours as well.

Comment: Just uploaded one of my updated app without any interruption, ITC seems fine. But any case this question is off-topic.

Comment: _general errors_ are usually problems on the Apple's side – if it'd been something on your side, you would've received more information / error codes etc...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments and sorry if this one seems off topic. I have accepted Neeku's answer as it seems to sum up the probable issue and with that I think we're done here. Thank you!

Comment: If you've read other posts then you may have already tried all of these:

- Clean/Clean build folder.
- Check all resources are included in your application bundle.
Restart XCode.
- Check that all developer profiles are correctly assigned in the project settings.
- Archiving in XCode seems to be a general problem, with appalling error codes to boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're the third+ person with the very same problem in past few hours, this is a temporary technical issue with iTunes Connect servers that should be fixed soon. Checking [Apple Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1006908#1006908), lots of other people have had the same issue in the past couple of hours:

> It seems that newly generated `.mobileprovision` files (since roughly
>   several hours ago) have a different formatting then before.
>
> When comparing mobile provisioning files that I've generated today
>   with older ones there are some obvious differences. Theres more
>   spacing between the elements and the private key segment is placed on
>   one line instead of 33(?) lines like before.
>
> Manually restoring the `.mobileprovision` file format to match older
>   ones does not help to resolve the issue.

I'd suggest waiting some more, or contacting Apple's Support Team (even calling them, since they're really good at answering phone calls) to see what they say.

See the iTunes Connect server status here:
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to wait it out to see if this resolves itself soon.

Comment: Haha! I like "resolves itself". Is it fixed yet?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Yes, Apple seems to have resolved the problem, though there was still a few issues that needed to be run down. The next day our provisioning profiles for distribution were no longer in member center, so I had to recreate them, but for some reason there was no push notification entitlement string... but in the end I ran it all down and everything worked, submitted and Apple actually reviewed / approved within 36 hours... so, it all worked out. Thanks for your help again!